# Making Dua to Marry a Specific Person

Tags: nikah, dua

Assalaamualaikum!

Is it possible that Allah changes the person one will marry if one makes a dua, because prayers can change fate of a person if Allah accepts that dua?

In other words, can one ask to be married to a specific person and does Allah accept these kinds of prayers or is it against His Fitrah?

Jazak Allahu Khair!

Answer (score 2):

alaikumsalaam!

There's a difference between fate and destiny.  Fate is the preordained path of life which happens in-spite of ones speech and action.  Destiny is predetermined thing within a person's life that one takes an active course in shaping.  In Islam we call it Qada' wal Qadr and both are from Allah.

We cannot control fate.  Death is fate, how, when, where we die is unknown.  But if we commit suicide, this is destiny under our control.

So yes, we can make du'a and ask Allah for us to be married to a specific person.  However, we also must take the steps and try to get married to whomever we like.  But the outcome is not in our control.  Anything can happen.  And whatever happens, we have to understand it was for our best interest, even if we dislike it.

Therefore, make lots of du'a and do your best in pursuing, hoping for the best outcome.  Allaho Alim.

Comment: How would you like to respond to this [Ayah](http://quran.com/42/20)? Maybe you should include more detail, as we know one can wish to Allah that to marry him to a believing woman, but can One make Du'a like "marry me to the most beautiful and richest girl"???

Comment: Allah orders us to marry.  Desiring a beautiful and rich girl isnt unislamic.

Comment: @Sayyid I agree with you.. it isnt wrong to ask Allah for such a woman.. but it is very much better to include the word pious as well.. because if religion is there.. life will be peaceful