# How to ask dua to marry a specific person?

Tags: nikah, dua

Assalamu alaikum,

from the question ["Making Dua to Marry a Specific Person"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11519/making-dua-to-marry-a-specific-person) i understood that we can make dua to marry a specific person, but i want to know how to ask dua ? any specific ways to ask the dua or any recitals ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allah (swt) understands all languages and knows exactly what you mean by your dua'a. I wouldn't worry about how my dua'a would sound. My suggestion is to speak to Allah and ask him what you want in a way that feels natural to you. One of the best times to make dua'a is while you are doing the prayer and that is when you make "sujud." Always start dua'a with praising Allah and thanking him for what he has giving us, and end dua'a by saying salawat on the prophet (pbuh)

Allah knows best.

Comment: k, Jazakhallah :)